# How to check if a table already exists in the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Now I am using something like:

```
IF (object_id('table', 'U') is not null)  
AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE id = 0))  
    RETURN;
```

to check if this 'table' already exists in my database but I get the next error message while running the script if there is no such table in the current database:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid object name 'table'.

Is this correct way to check if a table exists in a database? Or may be I must change any settings of my SQL Management Studio?

**ANSWER**: I changed my script and everything works well:

```
IF (object_id('table', 'U') is not null)  
    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE id = 0))  
        RETURN;
```

Comment: What is the whole script? `if (object_id('tablex', 'U') is not null) begin select * from tablex  end` works for me?

Comment: Script has been updated.

Comment: you need to put the usage of the table into a different statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (object_id('tablex', 'U') is not null) 
begin 
select * from tablex  
end
```

works for me. If the table does not exist then compilation of that statement should be deferred (assuming that you are on SQL Server 2005+).

If you are referencing the table in anything other than the statement immediately after the `if` you need to use `begin...end`.

### Updated.

You need to use

```
IF (object_id('table', 'U') is not null)
    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE id = 0))
       RETURN;
```

Your existing statement cannot compile as is. The whole statement gets compiled and all objects must exist at that point even if compilation of the statement has previously been deferred.

Additionally SQL Server [is not guaranteed to do short circuit evaluation](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/) in any case.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM sys.objects 
           WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'table') 
           AND type in (N'U'))
```

I ran into similar issues found doing the query as such helped. The `N` meerly indicates unicode

Comment: This has no benefit over the OP's method AFAIK. Just more verbose.

Comment: @Martin yea, it is just more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

This might work better for you

```
if (object_id('table', 'U') is not null)
  if not exists (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE id = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_NAME='QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS'))
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'EXISTS'
    END
```

where TABLE_NAME is the name ob the table you want to check in your database.

UPDATE:

if you're using SQL SERVER 2000+ msarchet answer is more appropriate, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many ways.

```
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM sysobjects 
        WHERE xtype='u' AND name='tablename') 
            SELECT 'tablename exists.' 
    ELSE 
            SELECT 'tablename does not exist.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u provide the Table Name to  [Table], if so try  to change it to  Something else. Then it will work fine i think. Then all the above said answers will work fine.